# Python Tkinter, how to synchronize multiple flashing widgets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This is my first question ever here !

I have created multiples customed widgets (based on canvas) that have the same flashing method.
When I click on them (using bind()), they should blink (using after() callback) until I click on them a second time.

That is working but their blinking is asynchronous because it starts when I click on a widget.

I would like to synchronize their blinking and I can not figure what to use.

I thought about a main blinking function that would sent an event to all the widgets but that would mean each widget will have a double binding and I am not sure that is possible.

Below is a simplified example :

```
import tkinter as tk


def flash(button):
    current_color = button.cget("background")
    next_color = "green" if current_color == "red" else "red"
    button.config(background=next_color)
    root.after(1000, flash, button)


root = tk.Tk()

Button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Button1", background="green")
Button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Button2", background="green")

Button1.pack()
Button2.pack()

Button1.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", lambda event: flash(Button1))
Button2.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", lambda event: flash(Button2))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have a single instance of `flash()` running at all times: it toggles the colors of every button in a list - that is initially empty.  The bindings for the individual buttons just add or remove the button from that list.

Comment: By the way, that simplified example is called [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You can store the blinking buttons in a collection (here in a set, as a closure that keeps track of which buttons are currently blinking), and use this to synchronize the blinking. I added a purge of the callbacks in order to avoid having many overlapping blinking commands.

(I also used `foreground` i/o `background` colors to make it work on my system.)

```
import tkinter as tk


def flash(button, buttons=set(), _after=[]):
    if button not in buttons:
        buttons.add(button)
    current_color = button.cget("foreground")
    next_color = "blue" if current_color == "red" else "red"
    for button in buttons:
        button.config(foreground=next_color)
    for after_id in _after:
        root.after_cancel(after_id)
    if buttons:
        _after.append(root.after(1000, flash, button))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()

    Button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Button1", foreground="blue")
    Button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Button2", foreground="blue")

    Button1.pack()
    Button2.pack()

    Button1.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", lambda event: flash(Button1))
    Button2.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", lambda event: flash(Button2))

    root.mainloop()
```

The following slightly more complicated function allows to stop the blinking of a button when it is clicked a second time; it works by checking if the call was a click or a callback; if it was a click, it removes the button from the blinking set.

```
def flash(button, callback=False, buttons=set(), _after=[]):
    if callback:
        pass
    elif button not in buttons:
        buttons.add(button)
    else:
        buttons.remove(button)
    current_color = button.cget("foreground")
    next_color = "blue" if current_color == "red" else "red"
    for button in buttons:
        button.config(foreground=next_color)
    for after_id in _after:
        root.after_cancel(after_id)
    if buttons:
        _after.append(root.after(1000, flash, button, True))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try doing sth. like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time


class Blinker:
    def flash(self, button):
        current_color = button.cget("background")
        next_color = "green" if current_color == "red" else "red"
        button.config(background=next_color)
    def ch(self, i):
        self.b[i] = not self.b[i]
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.b = [False, False]

        Button1 = tk.Button(self.root, text="Button1", background="green")
        Button2 = tk.Button(self.root, text="Button2", background="green")

        Button1.pack()
        Button2.pack()

        Button1.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", lambda event: self.ch(0))
        Button2.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", lambda event: self.ch(1))

        while 1:
            if self.b[0]:
                self.flash(Button1)
            if self.b[1]:
                self.flash(Button2)
            t = time.time()
            while time.time()-t<1:
                self.root.update()
Blinker()
```

Hope that's helpful!